# NotNullIfNotNullAttribute usage difference

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple extension method to capitalize the first letter or return null if the input is null or empty

```
public static string? Capitalize([NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(s))] this string? s)
{
    if (s.NullOrWhiteSpace())
        return null;

    return string.Create(s.Length, s, (chars, state) =>
    {
        state.AsSpan().CopyTo(chars);      // No slicing to save some CPU cycles
        chars[0] = char.ToUpper(chars[0]);
    });
}
```

And another simple extension method

```
public static bool NullOrWhiteSpace([NotNullWhen(false)] this string? value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value);
}
```

As you can see I'm using the attributes `NotNullWhen` and `NotNullIfNotNull`.
There are no problems with `NotNullWhen` but `NotNullIfNotNull` doesn't work same way:

```
string cap = "abc".Capitalize();
```

produces warning

```
CS8600 - Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
```

If I'm switching the Capitalize method's attribute usage to

```
[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(s))]
public static string? Capitalize(this string? s)
{
...
```

then the warning is gone.
Why is there the difference in usage? What does my usage do without `return`? If it doesn't do anything then why is it possible to use the attribute this way?

Comment: In addition to the answers below you're telling the analyzer the return value is not null if `s` is not null which is not true in the case of an empty string

Comment: that's true, thanks. What would be the right solution then?

Comment: returning an empty string in case of empty string is one

Comment: well, it adds some complexity as I want either writing a capitalized (optional) name in my database or null. So basically I want to eliminate empty strings and whitespace(s) here

Comment: The issue is that the analyzer is only aware of null values, empty or white space strings are meaningless to it and there's no way to express 'the return value won't be null if the input string is null, empty or only contains white space characters'

Answer (score 1):

`NotNullWhen(bool)` is a post condition describes the exit state of the parameter so it adorns the parameter.

`NotNullWhenNotNull(string)` is a post condition that describes the exit state of the return value so it adorns the method.

`NotNullWhenNotNull(string)` doesn't make sense on a parameter because it's saying "if this parameter is not null, then this parameter is not null", that's not an instruction you need to tell the compiler, it knows that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there the difference in usage?

Because they are different attributes.

> What does my usage do without `return`?

You tell the analyzer if the argument `value` is not null, then the argument `value` is not null. (So your usage did nothing)

> If it doesn't do anything then why is it possible to use the attribute this way?

This attribute is designed for output, and you can also use it for `out` arguments, but how to use it correctly is your duty. You can even have `if(true)` or `i=i` after all.